# android async return type onPostexecute

Tags: android

Why does this code give me an error in Android Studio that says there is an incompatible return type on line
**protected String onPostExecute(String result2)**

Async code here;

```
class loaderdd extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String result2 = "hello";

    return result2;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void progress) {
    //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
}

protected String onPostExecute(String result2) {

return result2;
}

}
```

I am just trying to get my head round this idea and get it working before trying more complicated stuff like http requesting in it. Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute` does not have a return value, it must be

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {
```

See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that onPost have void in return.

if you want some data from asyntask then the only way to do this is using a CallBack. You can do something like this:

```
new CallServiceTask(this).execute(request, url);
```

Then in your CallServiceTask add a local class variable and class a method from that class in your onPostExecute:

```
private class CallServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object[]>
   {
     RestClient caller;

     CallServiceTask(RestClient caller) {
      this.caller = caller;
   }


protected Object[] doInBackground(Object... params) 
   {
    HttpUriRequest req = (HttpUriRequest) params[0];
    String url = (String) params[1];
    return executeRequest(req, url);
   }

protected onPostExecute(Object result) {
    caller.onBackgroundTaskCompleted(result);
   }
}
```

Then simply use the Object as you like in the onBackgroundTaskCompleted() method in your RestClient class.

A more elegant and extendible solution would be to use interfaces. For an example implementation see this library. I've just started it but it has an example of what you want.